# about dataProvider

Tags: java, testng

I have created two classes. `first.java` and `second.java`. In `first.java`, I have some 2 to 3 method defined. and in `second.java`, I want to use those methods by creating instance of that `first.java`. My scenario is like below:

1. clicking on signbutton in first method
2. using dataprovider want to iterate i.e parameterize in second method
3. signout third method.

Here, first and third method i.e. @Test should run once and second method @Test(dataProvider) should iterate all are depended

Is there any way to declare or create instance of another class globally? so that I can use in all the methods in `second.java` or is there any other method?

I am using `TestNG`, `Ecplise` and `Webdriver` for execution.

This is what is am doing:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "DP1")
  public void enteruserdetails(String username, String pass)
  {
           Spage spage = new Spage(driver);
           spage.clicksign();
           spage.enterdetails(username,pass);
           spage.signout(); 
  }
```

I want to divide the this test in to three so that:

```
1) spage.clicksign() will be done only once  
2) spage.enterdetails(username,pass) will use DataProvider for iteration
3)  spage.signout() will be done only once.
```

Then how to create an instance of the class `Spage spage = new Spage(driver)`; I have to do it in all places i.e. `@Before, @After and also in @Test` or is there any way to declare it globally? Here `spage.java` is used in `sfirst.java`.

Comment: I seriously have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider putting ur setup methods in BeforeXXX methods and teardown in AfterXXX methods.  In your case, you can have signin in method annotated with beforeclass and similarly your signout in method annoated with afterclass.

```
@BeforeClass
public void signin(){
//clicksign
}

@Test
//the enter details and verifications

@AfterClass
public void signOut(){
//clicksignout
}
```

Comment: hi  thanks for the reply , then how to create an instance of the class i.e have creata an instance in each annotations before ,test and after or can create instance  of the class for Spage(driver) globally ?

Comment: I guess then what you are looking for is Factory : http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories  .  Look at the example with dataprovider and factory.  If that doesnt suite your scenario, then give a bit more detail on what u are trying to do in second.java

Comment: hi , in second.java i have methods which will perform some actions on page 1st mehtod click on sign in link 2nd enter user name password do some actions(here i will user dataProvider) 3rd method sign out

Comment: hi , in second.java i have methods which will perform some actions on page 1st mehtod click on sign in link 2nd method enter user name password do some actions(here i will user dataProvider) 3rd method sign out . In first.java page my scenario is i want to write three seperate Tests for three methods in which for one of the method i pass parameters by data Provider, which are in second.java class by creating instance of it.my question is about creating instance in each test or can i create global instance of that second.java class and test1 run once test 2 should use dataprovider test 3 once

Comment: I haven't a clue what you are trying to achieve.  Why cant you just invoke the class which has all your tests directly from testng?  If there is some data that you have to pass to these tests, like the driver, then have a threadlocal instance of that and then u can refer it or if there is any other data then factory can be used to initialize that data and create instance of class.